# force download remote file with CakePHP using CakeResponse::file()

Tags: php, cakephp

In http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#cake-response-file we can find the instructions to force a download of a local file, but if we pass the path as a remote file (for example an image in Amazon S3) the request fail because it still looks for the file in the local filesystem.

Using media views (http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/media-view.html) works fine with remote paths, but it's a deprecated feature.

What is the best approach to force the download of a remote file using CakePHP?

thanks!

Comment: Found anything?

Answer (score 4):

You could use a combination of HttpSocket to save it to a temporary directory and the new Cake-Response-File, I was looking for something similar to serve  files from a CDN and came across your question.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#cake-response-file

```
$this->response->file(
    $file['path'],
    array('download' => true, 'name' => 'foo')
);
```

Though I appreciate this would require a download to the local server - someone else might have a better suggestion but this will work while you test.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I was trying to avoid the download to the server because PHP can read the file directly from the source. For the moment I've implemented a solution with pure PHP i.e. not using the CakeResponse object

Answer (score 3):

You can workaround this by doing the following.

In your html template, your anchor tag should be like

```
<a href="link_to_your_action" target="_blank" download="file_name">Download file</a>
```

Then you can use the location method of Cakephp's [CakeResponse class](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#CakeResponse).

```
$this->response->location($remoteURL);
return $this->response;
```

OR

simply

```
return $this->redirect($remoteUrl);
```

## **Explanation**

***HTML Anchor tag:***

In the anchor tag you are using *_blank* to not disturb your current page. Then *href* is the link to the controller action. And finally *download* attribute tells the browser to download the file instead of opening. Note: Check [this link](http://caniuse.com/#feat=download) for browser support.

***Controller action***

Both the *location* and the *redirect* methods do the same thing to set the appropriate headers for response object.
I personally prefer the first method since it looks like a more direct way of doing this.